# IS there a way I can take multi-line input?

Tags: powershell

I want to take input in powershell but I want it to be multi-line, if I try to do this with `read-host` it doesn't work because when I press enter it submits. I tried this with  `` `n `` as well as `\n` but nothing works

```
$test = read-host Enter Stuff

Enter stuff: 

Test `n test \n test

$test

Test `n test \n test
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (1) 
  {
    read-host | set r
    set test -value ($test+"`n"+$r)
    if (!$r) {break}
  }
$test = $test.trim()
```

This will take a multi-line input. If you want to allow line breaks, I would just add

```
$test = $test.replace("<br>","")
```

Which would make `<br>` as a carriage return, but you can change it to anything you's like like so:

```
$test = $test.replace("Whatever you want","")
$test = $test.replace("CRLF","")
$test = $test.replace("Break","")
```

What it does is that it keeps on taking new `read-hosts` until one of the lines is blank then it stops. Each individual line is `$r` and the whole input is `$test`

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Is there a way I could make this require 2 blank lines so the carriage return thing is not necessary?

Comment: Try changing `if (!$r) {break}` to `if (!$r) {$i++}; if ($i -eq 2){break} elseif ($r) {$i = 0};` this worked for me

Comment: That worked great, thank you